# Adjoint of a Matrix Definition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, definition

Tom M. Apostol in his book "calculus Vol. 2" page 122 (see image below) defines adjoint of a matrix as the transpose of the conjugate of the matrix. Is this definition always correct ? Does it agree with the adjoint defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix), i.e. transpose of the cofactor matrix?

[image: shot from the book]

Comment: OMG. Sorry :) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are two different concepts. The one that one hears a lot about is the usual adjoint of $A$, which is simply, as you say, the conjugate transpose of $A$, usually denoted by $A^*$.

Comment: What about about adjoint of $\mathbb(A)$ in $\mathbb(A^{-1})$.

Comment: @Cloud JR I don't understand your question.

Comment: it is not my question but OP's question. He posted it as answer ( he is a new contributor) , so i posted under your answer , so that you can answer it , if possible.                                         Some people use adjoint to denote transpose of co factor matrix (which is used in $A^{-1}$). He is confused with use of adjoint  and are they equivalent. That's what the question says. But your answer is already clear +1. My fault.

Comment: @AnyAD, can the adjoint be defined as both the cofactor matrix of the transpose, AND the transpose of the cofactor matrix?

Answer (score 0):

What about about adjoint of $\mathbb(A)$ in $\mathbb(A^{-1})$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Remarks like this should be added as a comment, not as An answer. It is also not clear from your short sentence what you mean, so please try to elaborate if you have a full answer

Comment: hello, welcome to MSE. post this as comment